# Hide XML comments in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

XML comments (before methods etc.) used to hide the `summary` when collapsed. Now they show it (even when collapsed).

Is there a way to prevent that?

**i.e.**

This is what's shown:

[image]

when the following is collapsed:

```
/// <summary>
/// How do I hide this text in this view?
/// </summary>
public int abc;
```

Comment: Define "more collapsed" than what we see right now, i.e. one line?

Comment: @silkfire It used to be something like  `///`.

Comment: I'm using 2012 and when I collapse it show the first line which is typically `/// <summary>`

Comment: @juharr That's what I want. In VS2015 it shows the whole summary.

Comment: It wasn't easy to tell that from what you have.  Maybe include the uncollapsed version as well.

Comment: I couldn't see any settings for that. Probably they didn't think anyone would object to that behaviour :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2017, doing this:

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>Put your description here</para>
/// </summary>
```

Just shows `///<summary>` in a rectangle.

Answer (score 7):

I didn't like that change either, so I wrote an extension to revert to the VS 2013 behavior. I just wrote it last night, so I'd consider it a beta at this point, but I'll be actively using it and actively fixing any bugs that arise. Feel free to check it out:

https://github.com/refactorsaurusrex/squishy-vs

---

**Turn this...**

[image]

**... into this:**

[image]