# Hide XML comments in Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.5.1)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, xml-comments

When collapsing the XML comments for methods etc. It used to be that the summary was hidden. As I would like it to be. Then in VS2015 they broke this. I asked a similar question about VS2015 and got a nice workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44295976/939213) - to use `<para>`.

The workaround continued working in VS2017 until now. Now I updated to version 15.5.1 and the workaround is broken, (why??...) and I can't find a setting to change that.

Is there one somewhere?

Comment: So, you want to collapse the whole XML comments, right? Or only the <summary/> part?

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof The whole thing. I mentioned the summary because the rest is collapsed now, the only problem is the summary.

Comment: Hmm, still works on my VS, do you have any plugins installed? And do you have an example XML doc that doesn't work?

Answer (score 8):

The way XML comments clutter up the code has always bothered me. In the past I've tried a few different Visual Studio Extensions and they've always sucked.

However, I just installed [NoComment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=3dGrabber.NoComment) and it seems to do the job. I'm running Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7.3.

While I was looking for this I came across your question, so I thought I'd provide an answer. Hopefully you'll find it helpful :)

Comment: Just added NoComment through Visual Studio Marketplace. It works great!

Comment: This extension does not use async load, so it no longer works in VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

Since [NoComment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=3dGrabber.) is no longer supported. I found [Collapse Comments](https://github.com/mrlacey/CollapseComments) is the closest extension.

It works perfectly on Visual Studio 2019. It does a similar act of hiding xml comments. **With options to hide small (single-line), long (multi-lines), and documentation (xml) comments.**

Choose what you want to hide in the toolbar that you will see after installing the extension.

[image: Toolbar]

Click on the comment icon to show, click somewhere else and it will auto hide.

[image: xml comments]
[image: Long comments]

Quote of features the listed features by the developer in readme.md

> - Ctrl+M, Ctrl+C collapses all comments (and using/Import statements)
> - Ctrl+M, Ctrl+D expands all comments and closes all other areas
> - Works with C#, VB, and XML comments
> - Can also collapse (or expand) using/import directives
> - Can be configured to collapse comments when a document is opened